# Can I freely set members in php?

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

Can I freely assign something to non-existent or not-known-existent members in php? Is there any difference between member names and associative array index?

I there any difference beteween

```
$a = array();
$a['foo'] = 'something';
```

and

```
 $a->foo = 'something';
```

If there is a difference, then how can I create "empty" object and add members dynamically to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing [Arrays](http://php.net/array) (which are bags/containers for data) and [Objects](http://php.net/oop) (which are wrappings for data with semantic meaning and functionality).

### Array Access

The first is correct since you are using an Array which acts like a [HashTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or [Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) in other languages.

```
$a = array();               // create an empty "box"
$a['foo'] = 'something';    // add something to this array
```

### Object Access

The second is an Object access. You would use something like this:

```
class Foo {
    public $foo;
}

$a = new Foo();
$a->foo = 'something';
```

Although the better usage in that case is to use a setter/getter approach like this.

```
class Foo {
    private $foo;
    public function setFoo($value) {
        $this->foo = $value;
    }
    public function getFoo() {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

$a = new Foo();
$a->setFoo('something');
var_dump($a->getFoo());
```

### PHP Magic

However there is still an option to use [PHPs Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) to create a behavior like you describe it. Nevertheless this should be considers not the usual way of storing data to a object since this lead to errors and gives you a much harder time with (unit) testing.

```
class Foo {
    private $data = array();
    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }
    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->data[$key];
    }
}

$a = new Foo();
$a->foo = 'something';   // this will call the magic __set() method
var_dump($a->foo)        // this will call the magic __get() method
```

This hopefully did help you solving your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to assign arbitrary members to an object as you do on an associative array, you'll probably want to look into PHP's magic [property overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set).

Here's an example class that will let you just assign and retrieve variables (mostly taken from the PHP documentation):

```
<?php
class PropertyTest
{
    /**  Location for overloaded data.  */
    private $data = array();

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->data[$key];
    }
}
// sample use:
$a = new PropertyTest();
$a->foo = "bar";

echo $a->foo; // will print "bar"
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an empty class object and afterwards add properties to it, e.g.:

```
<?php
$myObject = new StdClass();
$myObject->id = 1;
$myObject->name = "Franky";
$myObject->url = "http://www.google.com";
var_dump($myObject);
```

...this should produce

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(6) "Franky" ["url"]=> string(21) "http://www.google.com" }
```

Personally, I prefer using object classes instead of arrays.

Comment: Yes, but w/out predefining them you will generate unnecessary notices.

Comment: Agreed... It is a loose procedural way of manipulating a quick class object. I definitely would rather stick to the strict class structure (OOP structure), as was suggested by @fdomig. Then you have the full security and inheritance functionality of a proper coded class (access members etc.)